# Yellow warning will down app performance in React Native its continues call infinite time (i.e. continues calling the function)

Tags: react-native

if yes(mean slow down performance) how to disable multiple yellow warnings i.e. I have two yellow warnings and its ignore one at a time. so how to ignore multiple yellow warning

Answer (score 0):

```
import { YellowBox } from "react-native";

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  "warning 1",
  "warning 2",
  "warning 3"
]);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**

> Use LogBox from react-native

**

For globally removing the warnings use LogBox inside app.js

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  LogBox,
} from "react-native";

inside the app class or functional component --

  useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs([
      "componentWillReceiveProps",
      "ViewPropTypes",
    ]);

})

OR,

componentDidMount() {
     LogBox.ignoreLogs([
      "componentWillReceiveProps",
      "ViewPropTypes",
    ]);
  }
```